# Had a question I remembered asking a few months ago that had an answer and both are gone

Tags: support, closed-questions

Now that's really annoying, I'm on the SE network all the time, why can't I get some sort of notification that some code snippet that I'd like to have gone back to is likely to disappear forever?

It was a question about using strange code constructs or something to that effect and I had an answer where a guy returned the session ID using delphi assembly and I'd like to know how he did it, any chance someone could resurrect that answer for me, at least so I can see if it's a good idea?

Comment: Gonna have to resort to [experts exchange](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/System/Windows__Programming/Q_21972647.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a second look, it looks like [What's your best unnecessary code?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8384/whats-your-best-unnecessary-code), from October 2010, is it:

```
function GetCurrentSessionId: DWORD;
asm
  mov     eax,fs:[$00000018];   // Get TEB
  mov     eax,[eax+$30];        // PPEB
  mov     eax,[eax+$1d4];       // PEB.SessionId
end;
```

Normally, however, you'd want to get [10k reputation to see deleted posts](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools).

Comment: That was it thanks for checking, I'm pretty sure it was that one it was assembly code which you can write inline in Delphi, not in pascal. Anyway, I found getSystemMetrics($1000) <> 0 which does the same thing (and [probably] works on the 64-bit compiler).

Comment: @PeterTurner Ah, I see it now: updated my answer.